# Load disk driver during Debian installation

Tags: debian, drivers, disk, debian-installer

I have a server with all disks connected to a controller LSI 3008 IT (non-RAID mode). Unfortunately disks are not detected during installation of Debian Wheezy. Nevertheless the controller can be detected if I installed mpt3sas driver manually from [here](ftp://ftp.supermicro.com/driver/SAS/LSI/3008/Driver/Linux/PH10-11.00/debian/rpms-1/mpt3sas-11.00.00.00-1_Debian7.0.amd64.deb)

Does anyone know how to load the driver during Debian installation so disks can be detected?

Answer (score 0):

Personally i get the entire scsi directory in /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/ (in example for jessie) on a pc freshly installed and put it in /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/kernel/drivers/ in initrd.gz of installer (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/how-to-view-modify-and-recreate-initrd-img/)

With that, no problem on all recent dell workstations (for us)